# Best approach to obtain the port of a QTcpServer in a child process?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

What is the best approach to retrieve the port number a `QTcpServer` in a child process is listening on, assuming we do not want to use fixed port numbers for our TCP servers? So far I have been experimenting with the following two approaches:

- Start a `QTcpServer` in the main process and send the port of the TCP server in the child process to the TCP server of the parent process. This works but is cumbersome.
- Print the port number of the `QTcpServer` in the child process to `stdout` and read the standard output from the child process to obtain the port number in the parent process.

Is there another obvious and clean solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Does your child process have any kind of conifg file? Where does it take port from?

Comment: The port is randomly selected by `QTcpServer`, by letting it listen on port 0. The advantage is that it will always listen on an available port.

Comment: maybe use shared memory?

Comment: This is rather unconventional, you'd expect the parent process to create the server and when creating the child, the port is already available to the child (assuming you do a fork() in a Unix process).